# Convergence of a complex series to a function with double poles on positive integers

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that the series $\sum_{z=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{(z-n)^2}$ converges on the complex plane minus the positive integers to an analytic function with a double pole at each positive integer.

Now by limit comparison test with $\frac {1}{n^2}$ we know that the series is absolutely convergent except at positive integers where it is not defined. More specifically, I am using that  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|\frac {1}{(z-n)^2} |}{|\frac{1}{n^2}|} = 1$$ I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{(z-n)^2}$ is analytic for each $N$ and converges locally uniformly to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-n)^2}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1) Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(z-n)^2}$ is well defined, ie, that defines a function $f(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{N}$

2)Note that, for each $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(z-n)^2}=\dfrac{1}{(z-m)^2}+\underbrace{\sum\limits_{n=1,n\neq m}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(z-n)^2}}_{\text{holomorphic in }V_m}$$ where $V_m$ is a neighborhood of $m$ (so that m is the only singularity there).

3) Remember the definition of pole

Comment: To prove that it is well-defined, I need to show that the sum converges. I'm not sure how that follows

Answer (score 1):

In addition to  what Martin Vacas Vignolo has suggested here is the argument needed to prove that series converges to an analytic function in $\mathbb  C \setminus \mathbb  N$: if $K \subset \mathbb  C \setminus \mathbb  N$ is compact then $|(z-n)^{2}|\geq (n -|z|)^{2}$. Use the fact that $K$ is bounded and ignore the first few terms to conclude that the series converges uniformly on $K$. This proves that $\sum \frac 1 {(z-n)^{2}}$ is analytic in $\mathbb  C \setminus \mathbb  N$.

Comment: which theorem are you invoking? how do you know it converges uniformly?

Comment: @DavidWarren Use M-test. $\sum_{n=[a]+1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {(n-a)^{2}} <\infty$.